# Replacing Div on Submit Not Submitting Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to replace a form div with a message which is working, but for some reason it's stopped the onsubmit from working in the form, so the message is displayed but the form hasn't submit.

Here is the Form:

```
<div id="domsearch" class="grid_4 right" style="padding-left:20px;padding-top:30px;">
    <form action='/dac' id="dac" onsubmit="return check_domain_input()" accept-charset='utf-8'>
        <input name="domain" class="searchdom" value="www." onclick="this.value=''"/>
        <input type="submit" class="grey-big-button-submit" id="search" name="search" value="search"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the JS to swap the DIV:

```
$("#dac").submit(function (event) {
$("#domsearch").slideUp("slow", function () {
    $(this).replaceWith(
        "<div id='loading' style='float:right;'>" +
            "<h2>Please be patient while" +
            "we check availability. <img src='/images/progress.gif'/></h2>" +
            "" +
        "</div>");
    $("#loading").delay(8000).slideUp("slow", function () {
        $(this).replaceWith(
            "<div id='results' style='float:right;'>" +
                "<h2>Almost There...</h2>" +
            "</div>");
    });
})
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

**UPDATE* With @Nicael help I've got it working after the first animation which is good enough, the only issue now is I want to add a third message the following should make sense but it just breaks the script:

```
$("#dac").submit(function (event) {
$("#domsearch").slideUp("slow", function () {
$(this).replaceWith("<div id='loading' style='float:right;'>" +
        "<h2>Please be patient while we check availability. " +
        "<img src='/images/progress.gif'/></h2>" +
        "" +
        "</div>");
$("#dac").submit(); 
$("#loading").delay(40000).slideUp("slow", function () {
$(this).replaceWith("<div id='results' style='float:right;'>" +
            "<h2>Checking All New TLDs & Preparing Results " +
            "<img src='/images/progress.gif'/></h2>" +
            "</div>");   
$("#results").delay(60000).slideUp("slow", function () {
$(this).replaceWith("<div id='delay' style='float:right;'>" +
            "<h2>Apologies for the delay " +
            "<img src='/images/progress.gif'/></h2>" +
            "</div>");  
    });
})

});
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` prevents the FORM to be submitted. So not clear what you are expecting?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are preventing your form from automatic submission by adding

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in the end.

In this case, you can manually submit your form after all the animations are completed by adding

```
$("#dac").submit()
```

to the second `replaceWith()`:

```
$("#loading").delay(8000).slideUp("slow", function () {
        $(this).replaceWith("<div id='results' style='float:right;'>" +
            "<h2>Almost There...</h2>" +
            "</div>");
        $("#dac").submit(); //<-- add it there
});
```

If you want to start the submitting before the animations, place the above thing at the beginning of `slideUp()`:

```
$("#domsearch").slideUp("slow", function () {
    $("#dac").submit(); //<-- place it here
    ...
```

Comment: Then he would not be able to apply the animations that he has applied

Comment: Not to be nagging, but it still would not submit, it needs to be unbound first :) So $("#dac").unbind().submit(); is correct

Comment: Thanks for your help, though adding this (both suggestions) doesn't work the divs aren't shown but the form submits. What I'm trying to achieve is for the form to submit then the animation starts whilst the form is processing, it's a domain search and sometimes can take a while so I wanted to display the messages whilst it's thinking

Comment: @csu I edited. Place `$("#dac").submit()` right at the beginning of your function `slideUp()`

Comment: Thanks, thats now submitting the form but the it looks like its stopping there as the replacement div doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This line will stop the formsubmission, you can unbind it after all the effects with this line:

```
$("form").unbind('submit').submit();
```